# How do I change the PopupAnimation in a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, wpftoolkit

How do I change the animation in a ComboBox for loading the popup that has the list of items?
(without having to make a template for the ComboBox in order to access the popup)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access the popup, one can do something like this:

```
Popup popup = (Popup)comboBox.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", comboBox);
```

Where obviously comboBox is your ComboBox. The key part here is that "PART_Popup" is the name of the popup in the ComboBox template (at least in the WPF toolkit).

So an example of a full piece of code, called when the ComboBox is loaded:

```
private void cBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cBox = sender as ComboBox;
        Popup popup = (Popup)cBox.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", cBox);
        popup.PopupAnimation = PopupAnimation.Fade;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this...

```
     <ComboBox>
         <ComboBox.Resources>
             <Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
                  <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" Value="Fade" />
             </Style>
         </ComboBox.Resources>
     </ComboBox>
```

Let me know if this works...

Comment: That's much more elegant than my solution and I would like something like that, but it doesn't seem to work. Does it work for you?

Comment: This won't work because typically the PopupAnimation property is set explicitly in the ComboBox template, and will take precedence over the Style setter.

Comment: @Abe: Cool, did not know about that! Here's more info that I've found on the topic - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=VS.90%29.aspx